# Linking CSS file in php document nested in pages folder

Tags: php, html, css, file-structure

Web development newbie here. My site is becoming large enough that recently took a few steps to help manage it including:

1. Using a separate header.php; footer.php; and navigation.php file with an includes tag.
2. Filed additional pages under root/pages. Below is a snapshot of my current folders:

- root

  - pages
  - assets
  - images
  - js
  - php

My issue now that I have nested additional pages (other than index.html) in the pages folder. When coding these files, the link/include files are causing issues, because of the relative/absolute file reference. Through some research I was able to use this php code which seems to work for the header, footer, and navigation menu:

```
<?php 
set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
get_include_path()
) ) );

include 'root/assets/header.php';

?>
```

The issue I have now is the css link no longer works either:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-services.css">
```

I have tried doing this with no luck:

```
<?php 
set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],
get_include_path()
) ) );

include 'root/css/style-services.css';

?>
```

How do I insure the referenced css also gets included when using a file structure and php include functions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the CSS file, just `echo` it. Like:

```
<?php
//
// your other cods here
//
$style_services = file_get_contents ("root/css/style-services.css");
echo $style_services;
//
// your other cods here
//
?>
```